# extract different values from file with repeated lines

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have one file with tousands of lines with values like:

```
{ TABLE "informix".gcpfpfin row size = 308 number of columns = 4 index size = 9 }

{ unload file name = gcpfp03535.unl number of rows = 0 }
```

I need to extract from those lines the variable values [gcpfpfin 308 9 0]

thanks for any help

SP

Comment: Are all values to extract after `**` and before `**`?

Comment: yes the ** ** are marks, I need the values between them

Answer (score 0):

You might use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (regular expressions) for this as follows, let say your file is named `file.txt` and its' content is

```
{ TABLE "informix".**gcpfpfin** row size = **308** number of columns = 4 index size = **9** }

{ unload file name = gcpfp03535.unl number of rows = **0** }
```

then

```
import re
found = []
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        found.extend(re.findall(r'\*\*(.+?)\*\*', line))
print(found) # found is list of str-s
```

output

```
['gcpfpfin', '308', '9', '0']
```

Explanation: I used pattern with capturing group in `re.findall` to get one or more characters after `**` and before `**`. Note that `*` must be escaped to mean literal `*` as it has special meaning otherwise and that we look in non-greedy manner `+?` which prevents getting single matching starting at first `**` in line and ending at last `**` in line. You might elect to adjust regular expression to better fit your needs.

Comment: thanks for your help, I apologize, but my post has an error, the asterisks were placed by the formatter and are not part of the original string:
{ TABLE "informix".gcpfpfin row size = 308 number of columns = 4 index size = 9 }

{ unload file name = gcpfp03535.unl number of rows = 0 }